# closed form for integrals involving error function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$ where $f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{(-\frac{t^2}{2})}$. Then is there any way to calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)^kf(x)^2dx$$for $k=2,3,...$ I started with $k=2$ and tried using $\operatorname{erf}(z)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{n! (2n+1)}$ to rewrite $F(x)$ but then got very ugly sums. so I gave up on this idea. I then tried to write a tylor expansion for $\operatorname{erf}(z)^2$ by trying to write $\Big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{n! (2n+1)}\Big)^2$ in one sum form but it was ugly again.

Now I think that Taylor might not be a good starting point. Would be great if you share your ideas on this.

Many thanks in advance.

---

Here is what I have worked out for $k=2$:
$$
\pi^{\frac32}\int F(x)^2f(x)^2dx=
\frac{\pi }{8}+\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left( -1\right)
^{k+1}a_{k}}{k!2^{2k+1}}
$$
where $a_{k}=(2k-1)!!\int_{0}^{1}\left(
1+x^{2}\right) ^{k-1}dx$, $k=1,2,3,...$.